# Selecting a range of wires based on a bitmask

Tags: verilog

I have a one-hot line that I want to use to select a range of wires. So for example if my selector line is `0001` I want to select `some_wire[2:0]`, if it's `0010` I want to select `some_wire[5:3]`, if it's `0100` I want to select `some_wire[8:6]`, etc. Currently I'm doing this with a huge case statement however this doesn't scale if for example I want to parameterize the module. Is there a more succinct way of doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Barrel shifters can be efficiently synthesized so it might be worth comparing any solution against the baseline where you convert the selector back into a binary encoding and use a shift.
For example, something like:

```
shift = 0;
for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
begin
  if (selector[i])
  begin
     shift = i;
  end
end 

shifted_wire = some_wire >> shift;
output = shifted_wire[2:0];
```

Alternatively, you could use a for loop to compute each bit independently via:

```
for(i=0;i<N;i=i+1)
begin
   output[i] = | ((some_wire>>i) & selector);
end
```

Comment: Is that type of for statement valid in verilog?

Comment: I think it depends on what you want to use for N.  Synthesis should work as long as N evaluates to a constant or a parameter, but I believe it will fail if you try to use a reg or a wire for N.

Comment: Cool I didn't realize you could do that. I haven't tried it yet but further googling suggests you can. Thanks!